# Possible options for ASP.Net MVC gridView with editable columns

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, gridview

What are possible options for MVC gridView with autoresizing, sorting, editable columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Telerik Grid](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc/grid.aspx) is a nice component worth checking out. There's also [MVCContrib Grid](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Grid) which is a little less elaborate in terms of functionality and might require some more code but it is very extensible.

Comment: I found this on MVCContrib [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827395/use-mvccontrib-grid-for-editing  But it wasn't detailed enough on where I would have the extension method set up. Would that be in controller? Would you be able to provide any better explanation to it?, possibly for extensions method on how to use it?