# Asp.net MVC GridView edit columns option

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, gridview, mvccontrib, mvccontrib-grid

I have the view :

```
<%= Html.Grid(Model.data).Columns(column => {
column.For(x => x.results)
    .Action(item => Html.ActionLink(item.results,"Edit").ToString(),
        item => Html.TextBox("result",item.results).ToString(),
        item => (Model.data == item))
       .Named("Results");
             column.For(x => x.refId)
                 .Named("Reference ID");
             column.For(x => x.fileLocation)
                 .Named("File Location");

                })
                .Attributes(style => "width:100%", border => 1)
```

And the controller looks like:

```
  public ActionResult Index()
       {
        //  IEnumerable<TranslationResults> results;

        StringSearchResultsModelIndex modelInstance = new StringSearchResultsModelIndex();
        modelInstance.getData();
         return View("SearchGUIString", modelInstance);
      }
```

the data:

```
 public class StringSearchResultsModelIndex : IStringSearchResultsModelIndex
{

    private IEnumerable<StringSearchResultModel> m_data;
    private string id;

    public IEnumerable<StringSearchResultModel> getData()
    {

        List<StringSearchResultModel> models = new List<StringSearchResultModel>();
        StringSearchResultModel _sModel = new StringSearchResultModel();
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
        {
            _sModel = new StringSearchResultModel();
            _sModel.fileLocation = "Location" + i;
            _sModel.refId = "refID" + i;
            _sModel.results = "results" + i;
            models.Add(_sModel);

        }
        m_data = models;
        return models;
    }

    public IEnumerable<StringSearchResultModel> data { get { return m_data; } set { m_data = value; } }
    public string SelectedRowID {get {return id ; } set { id = value; } }

}
```

when I click the edit button from ActionLink, I am directed to /search/Edit page, I understand that I need to have some code in controller for  //search/Edit but I am not getting the text box where I can edit the text in result cell. I am new to MVC can anyone direct me where I am should be going from here, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely this compare always returns false : `item => (Model.data == item)`.
This will prevent the edit box from being displayed.

Try rewriting the comparison as a compare between simple values (for example id's) or implement [Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) on your data class and use that in stead of ==

**[Update]**

The comparison is used to decide which row(s) should be displayed in edit mode, where `true` means 'render the row in edit mode'.

Say you want to edit the row that corresponds to an item with a given id. Your comparison would then look similar to this `item => item.Id == Model.SelectedRowId`.

In your controller you would do something like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id)
{
  var model = new StringSearchResultsModelIndex();
  model.getData();
  model.SelectedRowId = id;
  return View("SearchGUIString", model);
}
```

Note that you need to add the `SelectedRowId` property to your view model class.

On a side note, I'd recommend you do not let your view model load it's own data in the  `getData()` method. A view model should be nothing more than a container you use to transfer data from your controller to your view. Putting data into a view model is the responsibility of the controller.

Comment: How would I know what equality I check here, Model.data is  List of objects type "search" with different properties and it looks like item would just one object, how can I compare to find which one I am looking for in that list?  I am thoroughly confused now :(. Can you throw some light on this .action method and how to associate it with rows here?

Comment: @sharma I've updated my answer. Hopefully that makes things clear.